# Can metals be ionized by radiation?

Tags: plasma-physics, laser-interaction

In gaseous state a laser can ionize metal atoms and create a plasma. But what about the solid state? Is a high intensity laser able to ionize a solid metal?

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by 'ionize'? Does it include, in particular, the [photoelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect)?

Comment: if your laser is strong enough to do this, the metal won't be a solid at the end.

Comment: Yes, look up articles on laser ablation.  It's how many lab plasma devices work.

Comment: @A.C.A.C.: What if it's under extremely high pressure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ionize an atom means to remove one or more electrons from the atom. In metals, certain electrons are already free and not attached to specific atoms. This is exactly what makes metals different from non-metals. Flowing freely inside the metal these electrons create conductivity making metals good conductors. So in this sense one could say that metals are already "ionized" without an impact of a laser.

Under certain conditions, a laser beam may push some electrons off the metal surface. This could make the metal very slightly positively charged, but wouldn't create a plasma, unless the blast is strong enough to vaporize the metal.

Comment: Sounds plausible. I guess that even if the laser could pull some electrons from the surface this would be counterbalanced by huge the electron density from the bulk